# Can anyone explain this even though i have entered the path of android sdk in environment variables

Tags: android, cordova, cmd, command, prompt

Whenever i try to execute **"Cordova build android"** command in my command prompt, i keep getting the same issue :

> *Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting)*
>   *ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\magha\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk (DEPRECATED)*
>   *Subproject Path: CordovaLib*
>   *Subproject Path: app*

I dont even understand what went wrong, i have searched it up and i keep getting the result of entering the sdk path into the environment variables, and i have done that.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting it manually.Try to update your 'PATH' to include path to valid SDK directory.
Download sdk (you can use android studio for this).Add into environment variables
my installation location is change yours accordingly = C:\Users\ANKIT\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

set ANDROID_HOME=C:<installation location>\android-sdk-windows

but i did this (try above if you get error)
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\ANKIT\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=C:\Users\ANKIT\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

set PATH=%PATH%;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools

after that run cordova build android again in new command prompt

**FOR JDK**

Download jdk from below according to your system
https://codenotfound.com/java-download-install-jdk-8-windows.html
https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jdk8-downloads.html

remember download 1.8 or higher

ADD into environment variables
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\bin
set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%;